# Reading and displaying data from a Firestore Document in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

**Background**

I'm trying to build an app which shows a number of stores, in the home screen which is a function component *(mind this as I need to use hooks)* I have a scroll view which shows different stores.

**What I need**

When the user presses on one of the stores it should redirect it to a screen which has the information of that specific store. I have built the "store detail" screen but with static info, I want to replace all of that information with data stored in a firestore collection.

**Question**

How would one go about retrieving data from a Firestore collection in react native, then assigning the data from each document to a separate Touchable Opacity (I know about passing params with react navigation, I just don't know which param to pass when working with Firestore), and then displaying that data in the store detail screen?

**Sample code for context**

*App.js*

```
    <NavigationContainer> 
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={user ? 'Home' : 'Login'}
    screenOptions={{cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}}> 
    <Stack.Screen name="Home"options={{headerShown: false}}> 
      {props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} />} 
    </Stack.Screen> 
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{headerShown: false}}/> 
    <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen}  options={{headerShown: false}}/> 
    <Stack.Screen name="storeDetail" options={{title: ''}}> 
        {props => <storeDetail {...props} extraData={} />} 
    </Stack.Screen> 
  </Stack.Navigator> 
</NavigationContainer>
```

In this file you'll see that I've already called some data (Login and Register pass userData to the Home Screen), however in order to implement that method I depended on the response from the authentication method I was using. I imagine although, I will probably need to pass something as extraData, I understand what I should do, I just don't know how to fill the blank spaces.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, install the [Firebase SDK](https://rnfirebase.io/) in your app, so you can make queries to your backend.

I don't know if your sample App.js represents the current state of progress on your app, but I'm going to assume that:

- you already have your storeDetail screen built
- you know the store's id before navigating to the screen (eg in the HomeScreen)
- you pass the storeId as a navigation param when navigating to storeDetail

So in storeSetails screen, you can query Firestore when receiving `storeId`, and save the result to a state variable on success:

```
const StoreDetailsScreen = ({ route }) => { // route is passed as a prop by React Navigation
  const { storeId } = route.params
  const [store, setStore] = useState()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true) // show a loading spinner instead of store data until it's available

  useEffect(() => {

    const fetchQuery = async () => {
      const storeData = await firestore()
        .collection('stores')
        .doc(storeId)
        .get() // this queries the database

        if (storeData) {
          setStore(storeData) // save the data to store state
          setLoading(false) // set loading to false 
        } else {
          // something went wrong, show an error message or something
        }
    }

    fetchQuery()

  }, [storeId])

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <ActivityIndicator/>
    )
  }
  
  return (
    // ... store details
  )

}
```

Then you can use the data in `store` to render stuff in your screen

```
<Text>{store.name}</Text>
<Text>{store.email}</Text>
// ...
```

More info about how to use Firestore in RN: https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage

Comment: Sorry to get back to you so late, just now I'm reading your answer. This looks great! But I really don't know how to pass the id as a param. I'm thinking something alike: navigation.navigate('storeDetail', IDHERE). But how does the app know where to get that id from? Is it just a string which the app then references when querying the database or does it need to get it from somewhere before? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can pass id as a param like this `navigation.navigate('storeDetail', { storeId: the_store_id })`. More here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params
Of course this means you should have `the_store_id` available somehow. Usually you would have a more general query (e.g. getAllStoreIds) in the previous screen (HomeScreen), which would fetch the ids you need. You can store those in a state the same way we do it in the answer above, then use the content of that state to render a list where every element is a link to a detail page.

Comment: Thanks a whole lot! Your reply was great and helped me get a grip of everything. Once again, thank you so much for explaining so clearly.

Comment: Hey I'm unsure if you'll read this but I'm having a little trouble implementing your solution (been busy working on other parts of the app and this kinda got pushed back a bit),  I've done everything you said but once I try to display the information as in `<Text>{store.name}</Text>` I get an error message saying undefined is not an object. Everything in my code is exactly as you showed me.

Comment: Also trying to console log the storeId returns the proper id but trying to console log "store" returns undefined.

Comment: I don't know why its not working, but some questions you should answer are: did you configure Firebase correctly? Is the query working? Is it returning a valid payload? Does the payload contain store data that looks like when you expect coming from your backend? If you're getting store undefined, probably the query is failing at some point, or the payload is not being set to state as expected. You should probably look into that first.

Comment: Also, are you querying the right collection? Maybe you named your store collection differently than `stores` which is what I put in my example.

Comment: I changed the name of the collection and everything is configured correctly. I got it partially working right now. It can display the info once, however if I go back and try to query a different store it turns back that `store.image` or any other is undefined. I imagine it might have something to do with unmounting the component but I'm unsure.

Comment: Hard to say without looking at the code... maybe watch a tutorial about using Firestore in a RN project, could give you a better idea of what you might be doing wrong. Maybe something like this https://youtu.be/_Wq1ZPhL3ic

Comment: Thanks a lot! Once again,  sorry to have bothered you!